# How to fix NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: scala, testing

I use Scala 2.10.0RC1 and sbt 0.12.1.
What causes and how can I fix this runtime error (runs fine on 2.9.2)?

The exact error message is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$ArrowAssoc$.extension$$minus$greater(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Tuple2;

Comment: Your code is compiled with [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) support, but executed without it. Are you sure you are running it with scala 2.10.0 RC1 library?

Comment: i am using sbt 0.12.1 with these scala options `Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", 
   "-language:reflectiveCalls","-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps",
   "-language:dynamics","-language:higherKinds","-language:existentials",
   "-language:experimental.macros")`. I'm running the code (test) inside sbt. how do i verify that it's using the right library?

Comment: It's possible there is something like `scalaVersion in Test := "2.9.2"` in your Build.sbt file.

Comment: `inspect scala-version
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = 2.10.0-RC1
[info] Description:
[info]  The version of Scala used for building.`

there is no trace of 2.9.2. I also ensured that scalaVersion in Test is set to 2.10.0-RC1

Comment: As workaround you could try to use `(a, b)` instead of `a -> b` in your tests.

Comment: Here's the stacktrace:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Tests unsuccessful
 at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
 at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:123)
 at sbt.Tests$.showResults(Tests.scala:192)
 at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$inputTests$2$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Defaults.scala:373)
 at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$inputTests$2$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(Defaults.scala:373)
 at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
 at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        ...`

Comment: i tried using (a,b) instead of a -> b, still no joy. maybe it's happing in a library?

Comment: I remember having problems with sbt caching an old Scala version somewhere. After I removed `~/.sbt`, `~/.ivy2` and `~/.m2` the problem was gone. Later on someone told me that `sbt reboot` would also help, but I didn't have a chance to try that out yet.

Comment: hi Eugene, i tried both, still no joy.
However I get a new error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/actors/Actor$`

Comment: I just encountered the same problem and ended up deleting a folder that caches jar files for sbt-multi-jvm and that fixed my problem.  I suggest searching your pc for files named -2.9  or 2.10.0-M.  And just wipe them out.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: I ran into this error while using liftweb. The solution I found is to upgrade scala to 2.10.1, lift to 2.5-RC2. Deleting caches didn't help me.

Answer (score 10):

You're running the code with the wrong Scala version. This can have several causes:

- misconfiguration of the project with sbt – search for 2.9.2 in config files
- stale cache used by sbt – `sbt reboot`
- something else?

If you meticulously check all your sbt configuration files for 2.9.2 and then wipe out all caches, things should run better. Dependencies usually have a version number in the name of the jar file, so running a find on your system will likely point you to the ones you missed.